# "Made" vs "done" in "Many useless experiments were prevented from being made by an adequate theory"

Tags: word-choice

> Many useless experiments were prevented from being **made** by an adequate theory.

This is a sentence from an English textbook for Russian postgraduate students whose major is not English. The authors are also Russian, and at least the main author is a PhD in English. The sentence is supposed to teach you to recognize gerunds.

Is "made" correct here, or should it be "done" instead? If "made" is correct, what does it mean in comparison with "done"?

Please consider only these two verbs. I'm not interested in verbs like "conduct" or "carry out" although I know they would sound better.

Comment: Have you searched “make an experiment” and “do an experiment” (or similar phrases)? What did you find?

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I have. Generally, "done" seems to be a better choice, but "make" might also be possible but with a different meaning. Since the authors of the textbook should be experts at English, I wanted to double-check.

Answer (score 1):

"Make", "carry out", "perform" "do", and "undertake" are all appropriate to use when discussing experiments. "Do" may sometimes be considered a little informal.

> experiment
>
> noun
>
> a scientific procedure **undertaken** to make a discovery, test a
> hypothesis, or demonstrate a known fact.
>
> *"a laboratory which **carried out** experiments on pigs"*
>
> verb
>
> **perform** a scientific procedure, especially in a laboratory, to determine something.

(Oxford Languages)

> Experiment
>
> a test **done** in order to learn something or to discover if something
> works or is true:
>
> *Scientists are **conducting/carrying out/doing** experiments to test the
> effectiveness of the new drug.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Some sources disapprove of 'make', others allow it:

> COMMON ERRORS
>
> ► Don’t say ‘make an experiment’. Say *carry out an experiment or do
> an experiment*.

(Longman Dictionary)

> VERB
>
> 5. (intransitive) to **make** an experiment or experiments

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: In American English, "make an experiment" sounds awful. I gather that's not so elsewhere.

Comment: @cruthers -it wouldn't be my first choice in British English.

Comment: Ironically, the book "Collins COBUILD English Usage" says "make" is wrong: https://i.imgur.com/VzIwioa.png

Comment: @athlonusm - you have learned that not all dictionaries agree.

Answer (score 1):

"Make an experiment" is wrong. "Make" does not *collocate* with "experiment".

"Do" is correct and natural. "Do" collocates with "experiment".

The Oxford Dictionary of Collocations says that "do" collocates, but doesn't mention "make".

FWIW, that sentence is badly written, even beyond that one mistake. The author's PhD might be in English literature or grammar, but not in writing.

Answer (score 0):

"make an experiment" sounds (as George Orwell might say)  barbaric. While there probably isn't an actual grammar error here, a better word should be found.

The entire sentence could be restructured to avoid the (double) passive voice, and a better choice of verb, such as "carry out", "perform" or even simply "do"